# USB RF Receiver Mouse Hacking

Tags: c++, assembly, usb, wireless, drivers

How do wireless mice work, as in technically, the RF Receiver you plug in via USB (PnP)? I want to know how I would go about accessing the data section of the receiver and see either the actual code involved in sending information to the OS driver, or see the drivers involved to go about decompilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to know how the receiver talks to the mouse, or how the receiver talks to the PC?

The former interface is proprietary and will vary from device to device. For the latter, see here

http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/HID1_11.pdf